# Keep space for second line

Tags: html, css, materialize, cardview

I'm designing my site with [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) library.

I'm loading data from database and setting into `cardView`.
Now the problem is sometimes the text of `card-content` is small and sometimes the text is too large to keep in one line. So, it makes a second line. But this second line is making the card larger than other card.

Now, I want to keep second-line space for second line even if the text is small.

Anyone can help?
[image]

Comment: Give `min-height` for the text...

Comment: You can use `flex` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `min-height`  for your content section

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max-height` for the `card-content` so that it won't exceed the height you want.

Comment: then what about second line?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```css
        .main {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
        }
        .fcard, .scard {
            flex: 1;
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .scard {
            flex:1;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
     <div class="fcard">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </div>
     <div class="scard">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco .
     </div>
    </div>
```